# Powering microcontrollers by the circuit it's meant to control

Tags: power, circuit-design, best-practice

I often think about controlling things around my house that simply need their power switched on and off (e.g. plant grow lights) on a schedule or via WiFi.  I have ESP8266 and ESP32 boards laying around, but am unsure about how to power them in these projects.  The obvious and simplest solution would be to leech off the power that's already wired, but I worry that switching the load on/off will do something bad, such as:

- Consuming too much power in the circuit, resulting in under-powered load;
- Damaging the parts directly interfacing the power source while switching on or off;
- Cause a fire and kill me in the middle of the night;

Given the example below as a reference, if that load were something more sensitive to voltage fluctuations would you foresee it as a problem?  What if the source were AC instead of DC?

[image]

If there were some rule of thumb or best practice guide for this, I'm all ears.  Comments are welcome if you'd like to share your experience on how you power projects without having a separate wall wart.

Comment: You write: "The obvious and simplest solution would be to leech off the power that's already wired" - which would imply mains power. Then you give a drawing with a 9V battery. Which one is it ?

Comment: All of the concerns you mention are valid. But the question you ask is very, very broad and can't be answered easily for all possible situations. You should spend some time reading through the many answers that have already been given here for cases similar to yours.

Comment: I ask about the broad case because I keep running into this same situation with only differing power variables. Sometimes it's AC (not necessarily mains), sometimes it's DC.

Comment: _"If there were some rule of thumb or best practice guide for this, I'm all ears."_ - no, there is no specific 'rule of thumb or best practice' - it all depends on the particular implementation. _Any_ circuit can draw too much power, damage components or burn if not designed properly. Best practice is simply to design it not to do that. But without knowing the specifics of the particular design, **we cannot tell you specifically what needs to be done**.

Comment: @BruceAbbott  I've failed for over a decade to "get into" electronics, and your answer sums up why.  It turns out, this isn't a *science* like people evidently think.  Your comment is my entire counterpoint to that notion.

Comment: Re: AC vs DC - get a 9v power supply. Re: consuming power - you'd have to work out the arithmetic. Figure out the current used by the LED string. Figure out the current of your controller device, and relay. (if the relay is oversized, it may even be the highest of the three things consuming power there). Re: damaging parts ... mechanical relays can cause a voltage spike, but there are easy ways to fix that, look it up Re: burn house down in the middle of the night ... please keep it away from anything flammable.

Comment: _"turns out, this isn't a science"_ - No, it's a _technology_. You don't need to know any science to learn electronic design, but you do need to _study_ electronic design do do the stuff you are talking about.

Comment: @ARMANI Could you please make your question more clear? Otherwise it will need to be closed.

Comment: The relay does not need to switch ground, but it may need an RC snubber with twisted pair everywhere .  Beware of EMI causing crosstalk to the control signal.   The battery charger was left out for some reason?  A power transistor switch can be used instead of the relay switching the 0V side.

Comment: To be honest it seems like it would work fine most of the time and I wouldn't worry about it. The only exception would be if you are using a current-limited DC-DC supply and temporarily overload it at turn on time. But it will be obvious if you have that problem because the controller will reset every time you try to turn on the load. If that happens, you can try adding a capacitor to the controller or other countermeasures.

Comment: It sounds like you have something related to analysis paralysis. You want 100 percent confidence that everything will work before you even try. But that confidence sometimes comes from trying things to see if they work. If, instead of thinking about it for all these years, you had tried something (even if it was wrong) you would have learned something and advanced your own knowledge and experience. Happy New Year. I hope 2021 works out well for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different approaches to your problem and as the comments state, it may very much depend on the implementation, particularly what is the power source.

Powering from the main wouldn't have the same implementation as powering a system from a battery.

Another important point is the cost of the system, do you want something for a few $ or can you afford more?

If you power from a battery, what power do you allow yourself to pull from that battery?

---

**Implementation A:**

The simplest solution, but not the cheapest, is to have a "modular" design:

- Your board control a [static (solid-state) relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_relay). Those are usually quite robust, can usually handle DC and AC and you can select their power rating according to the load that you have, from a 1W lamp to a 10kW motor.
- You can power your board either using a small AC/DC (isolated) supply if you draw from the main, or a DC/DC converter (either up or down conversion) if you power it from a battery.

The reason for using a solid-state relay is that you can control it at low voltage with a low current draw versus a coil relay that will draw a fair bit of current and have an inductive effect, requiring proper driving electronics.

This allows you to always use the same board and same code and by replacing those two parts (power supply and static relay) you can pretty much face any situation, even switching heavy 3 phase motors.

**Problems:**

One issue though is that implementation is likely to draw a fair bit of current, it might not be a concern if it is powered from the main, but might be if it is powered by a battery.

One of the issues is that Wi-Fi is a power-consuming protocol (although new revision seems to go in the direction of low power systems with [Wi-Fi 6](https://semiengineering.com/wi-fi-6-for-low-power-iot/)). One has to keep in mind that the device is a receiver so it needs to be connected all the time.

---

**Implementation B, self-contained, battery-powered:**

It is basically called Low Power IoT.

A better solution than implementation A is to use low power wireless protocols like [BLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy) or [LoraWan](https://lora-alliance.org/) (long range) that uses pre-timed transfer frames. You can also make your own protocol over the 2.4Ghz range which sometimes is easier than using heavy stacks.

Some other protocols includes [Zigbee](https://zigbeealliance.org/), [MiWi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiWi) and many others.

**Understand low power wireless:**

A key point is to use a pre-timed transfer frame, which allows the receiver MCU to sleep between frames, allowing to drastically lower the power consumption of battery-powered implementation. The way it works is that the devices time-synchronize themselves and knows when packets of data are potentially sent. For instance, you can set a packet sync time of 500ms, which means an MCU would wake up every 500ms for 1ms which allows it to be in a low power state most of the time.

When you press the "on" button the sender will wait the next frame time to tell the remote switch to turn on.

The master can send a frame every 500ms regardless you pressed the switch to ensure it is always sync. If a receiver sees it doesn't receive anything, for example, it lost the sync, it can stay up and listen until the next frame and can resync itself.

[There are several implementations of such](http://hj.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:418819/FULLTEXT01)

Coupled with a low-power MCU and well-designed electronics, you can have such a system being powered from 2 AA batteries for a couple of years, 2 to 8 years are not uncommon. Some devices can run 2-3 years from a coin cell.

It is important to use low self-discharge batteries.

If the load is fairly small and not too inductive, like some LED lamps, you can use a [latched relay](https://www.morssmitt.com/product-categories/400202/latching-relays) which only draws current when it changes state and nothing when either enabled or disabled.

If the load is bigger or inductive:

- Option A: using a [latching solid-state relay](https://www.relayspec.com/specs/025600/NLF.pdf) instead of the latching relay A.
- Option B: using a solid-state relay with main as signal input going through the relay A
- Option C: using a normal relay/contactor controlled by the main through relay A.

Such a design would require a little more knowledge and make your own PCB but can be a great challenge if you want to learn more about electronics. It's quite a challenge for a beginner and you might pull some hair out but there are lots of resources online.

Avoid using the wireless module and look for an on-chip integrated solution like TI [CC25xx series](https://www.ti.com/sitesearch/docs/universalsearch.tsp?searchTerm=CC25#q=CC25&t=everything&linkId=1).

This implementation allows you to have a fairly robust system that is powered by its own batteries with a lifetime of a few years and can be self-contained in a PCB of a fairly small size. The latched relay provides isolation to the mains and if the relay isn't big enough in some situations, it is possible to add another, bigger one externally using the onboard relay as the primary actuator.

---

About your concerns about destroying the load by switching it this way, be assured that, unless you switch it on and off at high frequency, it is unlikely that you would damage it.

If you have a highly inductive load, for example, a vacuum cleaner, you need to be aware of arcing and the damage it can create to a relay, make sure it can withstand it, but in the most use case, it is unlikely you will want to remotely switch such a device.

Answer (score 0):

Triggering even relay from the same power source as controller may cause the voltage spike strong enough to reset the controller.

A rather elegant approach would be to power up the lights gradually rather than abruptly. This would eliminate the large power spikes that otherwise are likely when switching the lots of lights on and off. The simplest way to achieve this is by using some reference design of the programmable current source, like [this](https://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails/mcp1631rd-dcpc1). While it may generate some noise of its own, it will be the higher frequency noise, less by amplitude, so may be easier to suppress by the noise filter in power circuit of the controller.

And, of course, you also need a [noise filter](https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/lc-filter-for-power-supply-design-tips) for the controller power source, or at least some larger capacitor (50uF or about) across its power terminals. It is rather difficult to advice for which values should the components of the filter have but you can try various combinations till achieving the stable operation.